# Activiti REST returns 401 after GET request

Tags: angularjs, rest, cors, same-origin-policy, activiti

When i tried to send a GET request to Activiti REST URL, using POSTMAN and configuring an authorization parameter (*kermit:kermit*) it works like a charm.

But when i tried to do the same thing, only with Angular $http service, it returns the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/repository/deployments. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Here is my controller:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('doktorat-app-test')
    .controller('TestController', TestController);

TestController.$inject = ['$http', '$base64'];
function TestController($http, $base64) {
    var tcr = this;
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $base64.encode('kermit:kermit');


    tcr.text = 'ssdsds';


    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/repository/deployments')
    .then(function(response){
        tcr.text = response.data;
    });
}

})();
```

Has anyone encountered on similar error?
Spent more then 2 days trying to resolve this issue, but without any success.

P.S. I am using NodeJS http-server to run my Angular App, which runs on port 8081.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=No+Access-Control-Allow-Origin+header+is+present+on+the+requested+resource

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to access rest api which is on `http://localhost:8081/` From `http://localhost:8080/`, browser will check if your server implement CORS using preflight request. You can get detail about CORS on below url:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Normally application hosted in one server will not be allowed to access the resources hosted in other sever.This restriction is implemented by all most all browser now a days.

In order to make it work, your rest api server has to tell that some other servers will also be allowed to call. For this , you need to implement CORS filer in your rest api server.

Since you didn't specify which langauge you are using in REST, i am providing an open source CORS filter library for `JAVA`:

> http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html

which solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it gave me an idea how to solve my problem.
Since activiti REST is running on localhost:8080 Tomcat and its in his webapps folder, i stored my angular app also in webapps folder and solved my issue. It not an elegant solution, but in my case i just need it  to work. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To allow CORS for a specific domain you can use a middleware as below:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8081");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
    next();
});
```